Nullable integers - why does it not throw an exception?
I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended by design but I was hoping someone here would have more of an idea as to why it happens.
Consider this code
var someMetric = GetMetric(); // returns 3000
var someNullableMetric = GetNullableMetric(); // returns null

// Doesn't work
var total = someMetric + someNullableMetric; // why does this return null and not throw an error?
var Total = someMetric + someNullableMetric ?? 0; // why is '+' done prior to '??'

// Works
var Total = someMetric + (someNullableMetric ?? 0); // this understandably works

Just looking for an explanation as this functionality was totally unexpected, null coalescing operator doesn't fall into BODMAS so I would have assumed it would have been executed first (although last kind makes more sense now I'm typing it out)? or an exception would have been thrown for trying to add null to a value.

It seems like you've got two different questions: 1) "Why does int? + int = int? rather than a compile/runtime error?" 2) "What is the precedence of ???"

To answer the first question from the title, anyway. See null coalescing order of operation for the other.

Both of these follow the documented rules of C#.
someMetric + someNullableMetric evaluates to null due to lifted operators. If you want to force an exception, you can always use someMetric + someNullableMetric.Value instead. See the spec section 12.4.8 for more details.
someMetric + someNullableMetric ?? 0 is equivalent to (someMetric + someNullableMetric) ?? 0 because + has higher precedence than ??.
If you want an exception, use someNullableMetric.Value. If you don't want an exception, use (someNullableMetric ?? 0) as per the last line of your question's code. See spec section 12.4.2 for more details.

let me start  with following
var Total = someMetric + someNullableMetric ?? 0; 

here ?? (null-coalescing operator) has lower precedence than the + operator.
so it will be interpreted as
 int Total = (someMetric + someNullableMetric) ?? 0;

now let's talk about this
var total = someMetric + someNullableMetric; 

in this expression you are adding an int to an int?, the result is an int? because the operation promotes the int to int? to handle the possibility of null.
Since someNullableMetric is null, the result of the addition is null (because any arithmetic operation involving null results in null in the context of nullable types).
Therefore, total is assigned null. so try
 int total = someMetric + someNullableMetric; 

this will not compile
